# array_shift and print_r behaving wierd in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to test `array_shift` on a simple example:

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$rem = array_shift($a);
print_r($rem);
```

Which only returns me: `a`, instead of an array of: `['b', 'c', 'd']`.

[php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) docs on `array_shift` state the following:

> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
>   shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All
>   numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero
>   while literal keys won't be affected.

This function is supposed to remove the first element and return all the rest with re-ordered keys.

Now, I copied the example from the docs site as is (tried with both `[]` and `array()`):

```
$stack = ["orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry"];
$fruit = array_shift($stack);
print_r($stack);
```

Now this returns as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => raspberry
)
```

I don't understand what just happend here or what I did wrong.

My example only differs in variable names and elements in the array.

And I **hardly** don't believe the issue would be because of my usage of single-quotes `'`.

Also, here is a [demo on Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9cd2c7e1e25020d23934b9faba1a4bdbeffa17b3).

Comment: In second example you are printing $stack and n first example you are printing $rem. It returns first value and it modify the actual array.

Comment: @AjayKumar Yes. These things can happen in PHP's world of `passing by reference` :) Now I can't delete this question :)

Comment: Read carefully. array_shift() **returns** the first element and removes it from the array. The array itself is altered, but you receive the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_shift()` is a stand-alone function - you don't need to assign it to a value, it automatically unsets it from the given variable:

```
<?php
    $a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    array_shift($a);
    print_r($a);
```

https://3v4l.org/GEr3g

Comment: Yes! Now I see. It's passed by reference, thus the docs say: `array_shift ( array &$array ) : mixed`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> `array_shift()` shifts the first value of the array off and returns it

The *"it"* refers to *"the first value"*, not to *"the array"*. It shifts off the first value and returns said first value; the array is being shortened by that process. Pay close attention to what is being returned in the example code (`$fruit`) and what you print (`$stack`).

To leave the original array intact and return a new, shorter array, you'd do:

```
$rem = array_slice($a, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you example `$rem` is the return from the function `array_shift` as stated on the doc it will return the eliminated index value, on the other side whenever you print

```
 print_r($a);
```

This will return the array after the function performed.

Answer (score 0):

As the php doc [array_shift](https://www.php.net/array_shift) shows.

The return result of `array_shift` is the first value of the array that been shifted off, and remove the first value of the original array.

> ```
> array_shift ( array &$array ) : mixed
> ```
>
> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
>   shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All
>   numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero
>   while literal keys won't be affected.